# DbContext and DbSet issues in Generic repository

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, generic-programming

I'm trying to create a project will play the repository role in all my projects.

**The Idea:**

The Idea was inspired from **Generic Repository pattern**, so I'm trying to create a `generic class` will be the repository.
this class will receive the `dbcontext` at the Instantiation.
this class will implement an `Interface`.

**The Interface :**

```
interface IRepo<Tcontext> where  Tcontext : DbContext
{
    void GetAll<Table>();
}
```

**The Repo class :**

```
public class Repo<Tcontext>:IRepo<Tcontext> where Tcontext: DbContext
{
    private Tcontext _Context { get; set; } = null;
    private DbSet    _Table   { get; set; } = null;


    public Repo()
    {
        _Context = new Tcontext();
    }
   

    public void GetAll<Table>()
    {
        _Table = new DbSet<Table>();

        return _Context.Set<Table>().ToList();
    }
}
```

So, the Idea, lets imagine we have this dbcontext class: `DBEntities`, and if I want to select all records from `Client` table, and after that in another line I Wanna select all records from `Order` table

**I would use:**

```
        Repo<DBEntities> repo = new Repo<DBEntities>();

       var clients repo.GetAll<Client>();
       var orders repo.GetAll<Order>();
```

**What is the problem:**

the problem in `Repo` class.
the problem is four errors I don't have any Idea how can I solve them.

**Errors:**
[image]

[image]

so please, **any help to solve this problem?** and massive thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two errors `The Table must be a reference type....` is logged as you have not defined the constraints on your function. Change the signature as shown below; using the below signature the method is putting constraint that generic type `Table` should be reference type.

```
public void GetAll<Table>() where Table : class
```

The third error as there is no public default constructor for DBContext. You should use the parametrized one. Check the DBContext definition [here](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs)

```
_Context = new Tcontext(connectionString);
```

The fourth error will resolve automatically after adding the changes for first two as generic parameter `Table` constraint is defined. You can check the signature of `Set` function at [here](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs#L255).

Comment: I still have these errors https://imgur.com/qyTaIxZ

Comment: 1) The constraint should be defined at both interface and class implementation. 2) Your method `GetTable` is having return type as void? Should it not be the appropriate type.

Comment: massive thanks sir this is very helpful, I appreciate this for you sir, but I have a small note about your answer I didn't need to send the connection string to the `DBContext` it's work without the `connection string`